# Contourlines on grayscale image

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, contour

I'd like to draw contour lines on a grayscale image. Since different contour lines are drawn the grayscale image is first converted into rgb space in order to be able to draw colored contour lines.

imports:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import torch
from skimage import img_as_ubyte, img_as_uint, img_as_float32
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

include_classes=['bg', 'cap', 'pz', 'cg', 'prostate']

rgb_dict = {
    'bg': [0, 0, 0],
    'cap': [255, 0, 0],
    'pz': [0, 255, 0],
    'cg': [0, 0, 255],
    'prostate': [255, 255, 0]
}
```

A: The original image: `image = img_as_uint(image.detach().numpy())`

[image]

B: After conversion to rgb space: `image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)`

[image]

C: Adding the contour lines: `cv2.drawContours(image, contours, -1, rgb_dict[include_classes[i]], 1)`

[image]

The problem seems to happen in matplotlib:

`Clipping input data to the valid range for imshow with RGB data ([0..1] for floats or [0..255] for integers).`

The `image` max value is 1078 and the min value is 0. If it is clipped to [0, 255] then of course some information is lost.

I'd like to get the contour lines on the first original image (A). But how do I achieve this?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: This question is not reproducible without **data**, `contours` and `rgb_dict[include_classes]`. Always provide a complete  [mre] **with all relevant code, data, errors, current output, and expected output, as [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)**. If relevant, plot images are okay.

Comment: still needs an example of `contours`, as far as I can tell.

Comment: thanks for the answer. the image is a float pytorch float tensor which was converted to numpy. However, the scale was not b/w 0 and 1 but rather some arbitrary floating point numbers. So feature scaling and converting to ubyte did the trick.

Comment: Often, the act of preparing a question to present on SO, leads individuals to resolve the issue.